# How can I use pen pressure property in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm use this code for get pressure property but does not work. Why `GetPointerPenInfo` function return false?
`LastError` function return 87 (incorrect parameter)

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Winapi.wmPointer, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure PenEvent(var msg: TWMPointerUpdate); message WM_POINTERUPDATE;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation


{$R *.dfm}
{ TForm1 }


{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.PenEvent(var msg: TWMPointerUpdate);
var
  pInfo: PPointerPenInfo;
begin
  if GetPointerPenInfo(msg.pointerId, pInfo) then
    Label1.Caption := inttostr(pInfo.pressure);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Your pointer (pInfo) does not point anywhere, that's not how you use a pointer. Although I don't know how the function is declared, my guess is, you should be good to pass a "var" TPointerPenInfo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing an **uninitialized pointer** to `GetPointerPenInfo()`.  Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.PenEvent(var msg: TWMPointerUpdate);
var
  Info: TPointerPenInfo;
begin
  if not GetPointerPenInfo(msg.pointerId, @Info) then RaiseLastOSError;
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Info.pressure);
end;
```